# syntax for find element by css selector in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, autologin

my code

```
driver.find_element(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click()
driver.quit()
```

after running
error

> > C:\Users\amalp\OneDrive\Desktop\pico.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
> > driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "C:\Users\amalp\OneDrive\Desktop\pico.py", line 11, in 
> > driver.find_element(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click()
> > AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'cssSelector'

Comment: Your code does not seem to match the correct syntax. see documentation here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
driver.find_element(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click()
```

Try

```py
driver.find_element(By.cssSelector,"button[type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: tried driver.find_element(By.cssSelector,"button[type='submit']").click()
still not working
C:\Users\amalp\OneDrive\Desktop\pico.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amalp\OneDrive\Desktop\pico.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.cssSelector,"button[type='submit']").click()
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'cssSelector'